# How To Generate Random Float Value in ROBOT FRAMEWORK

Tags: python, robotframework

Actually I want a number which is random and float value
for Integer value i used

```
${Impressions_Int}=             Evaluate    random.randint(0,19999)
Log                             ${Impressions_Int}
```

I don't know what should we use for random float value

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way of getting a random float is to use the uniform  `random.uniform(a, b)`

Example:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Random Float
    [Documentation]  This is some basic info about the test
    [Tags]  Smoke
    ${random_float} =   Evaluate    random.uniform(1.1, 1.9)  modules=random
```

Result:

```
${random_float} = 1.407633348084447
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not quite clean solution - but what I sometimes do is just generate two strings and conc them on the output:

```
Random Float
  [Arguments]    ${wholeNumber}=2    ${decimalPoint}=2
  ${number1} =    Generate Random String    ${wholeNumber}    123456789
  ${number2} =    Generate Random String    ${decimalPoint}    123456789
  [Return]    ${number1}.${number2}
```

Not the best solution ever BUT very easy and well understandable by QA peeps. :)